# array to display in the uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i recieved the string value from the server like this from the server output:-
loginStatus  baratiyar senior girls school$baratiyar senior boys school$baratiyar junior boys  school$baratiyar junior girls school$gandhi senior girls school$gandhi junior girls school$nehru senior girls school
then using string

```
   -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSMutableString *schoolStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"loginStatus  %@",schoolStr);
    recievedSchool= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[schoolStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                     [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"$"]]];
 //   [self getTeacher:schoolStr];
 //  [newschool addobject :schoolStr];

    [recievedSchool addObject:schoolStr];
    NSLog(@"array value is %@",recievedSchool);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [schoolStr release];
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
```

}

then while i  reload the tableview

i'm geting the count value

```
the count is 7
```

but i'm getting exe bad error while loading the data int the cell

Comment: you need to post you table view methods

Comment: check out my answer in above question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[recievedSchool retain];
```

is the issue

Comment: yeah forgot to retain the value tanks